# Creating ~/.vimrc disables syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, vimrc

I started using Vim as it was first installed and then decided to change the indentation behavior by adding

```
set tabstop=8 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=2 smarttab
```

to `~/.vimrc` as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878974/redefine-tab-as-4-spaces. However, when I do so, syntax highlighting for my Python files is disabled. I assume it is probably disabled for other languages and that other settings are not set from the default configuration, as well, but haven't tested yet.

How do I keep the rest of the default settings and only modify the above settings for indentation? (Note: I did not have a `~/.vimrc` before this. I created it and added the single line above.)

Answer (score 14):

Your system default vimrc no longer gets loaded when you create your own (and that's as it should be).

You also won't get filetype based indenting and other things.

The solution is to add these lines to `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype indent plugin on
syntax on
```

Comment: What if I want to keep those "other things" as well? What can I do?

Comment: Locate the file and add a `:source` command in your vimrc.

Comment: How to locate the file ? Where can it be ?

Comment: @xtof54 Without a ~/.vimrc, do :scriptnames

Comment: source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

Answer (score 14):

Or you can move the content of your `~/.vimrc` file to `~/.vim/plugin/CUSTOM_NAME.vim`.

Vim will automatically load your configurations (*without touching any other defaults*)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since it doesn't interfere with the defualt behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I needed this answer for MSYS2 (but not -- weirdly -- Cygwin)!

Answer (score 2):

What I found is that the vim installation didn't contain a system default `vimrc` at e.g. `/etc/vimrc`, but it did supply some settings in `/etc/skel/.vimrc` which resembled the default configuration, unlike what you get if you just do `syntax on` in an otherwise blank `.vimrc`, and could be copied to an existing account as a starting point.